# Maximum file Size(larger file) error when upload in laravel

Tags: laravel

Here is my code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request,[

            'name'=>'required',

            'file'=>'required|max:3000|mimes:doc,docx,jpeg,png,jpg,pdf,ppt,pptx',

            'Subject'=>'required',


        ]);
       if($request->hasFile('file'))
        {
            //return $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = $request->file->store('public');
            $filesize = $request->file('file')->getClientSize();
        }

        $file=new file;
        $file->name =$request->name;
        $file->file =$fileName;
        $file->Subject =$request->Subject;
        $file->size=$filesize;

        $file->save();
        return redirect(route('file.index'));
    }
```

**But When i run the code this error appear**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $max = $this->getPostMaxSize();

        if ($max > 0 && $request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') > $max) {
            throw new PostTooLargeException;
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

**This Error appear along with this code (PostToLargeException) larger file size**

How can i solve this error of large file my file size is 15MB .ppt format but when i upload small size format it upload i want maximum 100Mb file size
And max:10000 whats it mean?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That method `getPostMaxSize()` is checking the config you have for `post_max_size`. You will need to update that in your php.ini file to the amount you want. Also check out `upload_max_filesize`.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

E.g.

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 110M

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

You can check where your php.ini is located by running `phpinfo()` on an empty page. If you are using apache, you will have to restart it after you make edits:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Sir how can i access this php.ini file into my laravel project?

Comment: Did you edit the file that was marked as `Loaded Configuration File` from running `phpinfo()`? Sometimes there will be more than 1 if you have multiple versions of PHP. You also have to restart apache afterward, see my edited answer.